# Can gpsd change the firmware of a gps receiver?

Tags: drivers, firmware, gps, crossplatform, crossover

A while ago, I've tested the Global Sat BU-353-S4 gps receiver on Windows 7 and worked well when tested with software that used it. 
At the same time, it did not work on Ubuntu, followed many tutorials. In the end I did "sudo chmod 666 /dev/ttyUSB0" and it works fine, except that when using navit, there is a delay of about 10 seconds from the position navit process and my actual position(when driving).

Now, back to Windows 7 and the receiver does not work at all. The xgps binary that came with the drivers just shows some red text. When it used to work, it showed black text. It did complain about the drivers at one point, but even after reinstalling them, it still did not work. Initially I thought GPS Gate might have wrecked the drivers. I uninstalled GPS Gate as well.

So, after giving access to the driver file, could it be that gpsd has modified the firmware? Is there a way to restore it to default?

Not entirely sure if the receiver has just broken during this period or not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prior to setting the `-b` flag in `/etc/defauls/gpsd`

```
# Default settings for gpsd.
# Please do not edit this file directly - use `dpkg-reconfigure gpsd' to
# change the options.
START_DAEMON="true"
GPSD_OPTIONS="-n -G -b"
DEVICES=""
USBAUTO="true"
GPSD_SOCKET="/var/run/gpsd.sock"
```

The `-b` flag is:

> Broken-device-safety mode, otherwise known as read-only mode. A few bluetooth and USB receivers lock up or become totally inaccessible when probed or reconfigured

We found this true for the occasional gps unit that would be returned to a Windows system.

We weren't sure how to fix the non-responsive units.  It appeared something had *latched* (one source said it latched into SiRF binary), so they were pried apart and the battery was removed to clear its memory.  The battery was re-inserted and the plastic shell glued back together.  Tedious.

Subsequently we encountered this procedure:

> In order to switch your device back to NMEA protocol, you must follow these instructions on Windows:

1. Download and install this software:
   http://www.usglobalsat.com/store/downloads/SiRFDemo387.zip
2. Run the SiRf Demo software.
3. Connect your device, choose the correct COM port, and select the 4800 baud rate.
4. Go to Action > Open Data Source.
5. Next, go to Action > Synchronize Protocol & baud rate.
6. Then, go to Action > Switch to NMEA Protocol.
7. In the pop-up window, select the 4800 baud rate under the Baud Rate and click Send.
8. Close the SiRf Demo software.

The instructions continued:

> Now, try your GPS Receiver with the GPSInfo Utility
>   (http://www.usglobalsat.com/store/downloads/GPSInfo.zip) to see if the
>   problem persists.
>
> Note: Be sure and not to click on anything else in this software, as
>   you can render your device unusable.

However, since adding the `-b` flag we have had no more gps units stop working when no longer being handled by gpsd in a Linux system and have never tested them.

Comment: Can't one up this because I do not have enough rep, it's been really helpful, I will make sure to one up your answer when I get the points. Thank you! I'd like to return the favor, if I can help somehow, please leave a comment on this page in case you need help.